# split a string based on a .txt and space

Tags: bash

I have a list of filenames with spaces in a variable called file
and I want to loop over the files and get the file names

```
files='a 1 .txt b 1 .txt c1.txt d 2 3 .txt'
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $files; do echo $file ; done;
```

My expected output is

```
a 1 .txt 
b 1 .txt 
c1.txt 
d 2 3 .txt
```

I am not sure how to split the string any ideas ?

Comment: How is your `files` variable getting set?

Comment: Its set via files=$(ls *.txt) and there are files with spaces and withoutspaces

Comment: Okay, there's your problem. Don't do that.

Comment: Hi larsks i cannot change that line as that is a part of someone else's code and that is used in many places

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (There is a reason that is ***Pitfall Number 1***)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB**: This is a *really* bad idea. Don't do this. Fix the code that is setting the variable.

You could use `awk` to split the string, like this:

```
awk -F'.txt ?' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%s.txt\n", $i}' <<<$files |
while read filename; do
  echo "doing something with \"$filename\""
done
```

This will produce on output:

```
doing something with "a 1 .txt"
doing something with "b 1 .txt"
doing something with "c1.txt"
doing something with "d 2 3 .txt"
```

But here's a better idea:

If you want to put a list of files (possibly containing spaces) in a variable, don't do this:

```
files=$(ls *.txt)
```

As you've seen, you end up with what is basically garbage. Using `find` and `xargs` to process the files, as in:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

Or iterate over the output of ls in a loop:

```
while read filename; do
    ...do something with $filename here...
done < <(ls *.txt)
```

There may be other solutions as well depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: On the last case, probably best to at least use `ls -1` (if at all). Instead if in a single directory a simple `for i in *.txt; do ...` would probably be better.

Comment: Thanks a "ton" for not only answering this question but also more importantly showing me the right way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Perl one-liner also.

```
> export files='a 1 .txt b 1 .txt c1.txt d 2 3 .txt'
> perl -ne 'BEGIN{@arr=split(".txt",$ENV{files});foreach(@arr){~s/(^\s*)|(\s+$)//g;print "$_.txt\n"} exit } '
a 1.txt
b 1.txt
c1.txt
d 2 3.txt
>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the question I would have resorted to your trick because perl is all powerful with that split function

Comment: Could you please consider upvoting the answer

Comment: Done :) people like you should be encouraged more and more for sharing knowledge